# Сan't run examples. Couldn't find artemis.home error

Tags: activemq-artemis

I get an error when I want to run any example  through `mvn verify`

```
[ERROR] ********************************************************************************************
[ERROR] Could not locate suitable Artemis.home on either D:\Documents\IdeaProjects\activemq-artemis\examples\features\standard\security\..\..\..\.. or D:\Documents\IdeaProjects\activemq-artemis\examples\features\standard\security\..
\..\..\..\artemis-distribution\target\apache-artemis-2.18.0-SNAPSHOT-bin\apache-artemis-2.18.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] Use the binary distribution or build the distribution before running the examples
[ERROR] ********************************************************************************************
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.087 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-26T22:03:39+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.activemq:artemis-maven-plugin:2.18.0-SNAPSHOT:create (create) on project security: Couldn't find artemis.home -> [Help 1]
```

I tried to specify the path to the directory with artemis at startup, but it does not help `mvn verify -Dartemis.home="D:\Documents\apache-artemis-2.17.0"`

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears you're running the example directly from the project source since it reports `2.18.0-SNAPSHOT`. If that's the case then you should do what the `ERROR` message indicates:

> Use the binary distribution or build the distribution before running the examples

You can get a snapshot binary distribution [here](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/activemq/apache-artemis/) or you can build the distribution from the source using `mvn install -Prelease -DskipTests`.

If you *must* point the example at a different home directory you can do so using the `activemq.basedir` system property, e.g.:

```
mvn verify -Dactivemq.basedir="D:\Documents\apache-artemis-2.17.0"
```

Or you can change the `activemq.basedir` property defined in the example's `pom.xml`.

Comment: Thanks, would be good to add that somewhere in https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/examples.html. Especially since that doing a -Dartemis.home does not work ;-) (neither does doing a -Dartemis.basedir since it should be activemq.basedir cost me an additional 30 minutes ;-))

Comment: I'm a bit confused, @Kukeltje. Were you also trying to run the examples from the source directory without first building the release? What exactly do you think needs to be added to the docs?